# Can I use my USB Type-C which supports DisplayPort in alternate mode to connect to a HDMI 2.0 supported 4K TV

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, 4k-resolution

My laptop is HP Probook 450 G5. It has HDMI 1.4b and USB type-c with DP alt mode. I want to connect this laptop to my Samsung NU7100 TV which supports 4K@60Hz and has HDMI 2.0 ports. When I connect the TV via a HDMI cable, it only can run 4K@30Hz.

Can I take advantage of my USB Type-C port with DP alt mode to achieve 4K@60Hz? What cables or adapters do I need if this is possible? Can there be issues when connecting multiple converters? (Like USB Type-C -> DP -> HDMI). Also, does my USB Type-C support HDMI in alt mode as well?

Comment: USB Type-C is only a connector. You are getting the max possible for HDMI 1.4b, and for getting more you need HDMI 2.0.

Comment: @harrymc but since USB Type-C supports DP doesn't that mean it can achieve 4K@60Hz theoretically?

Comment: You can just query on Amazon for "USB C to HDMI Adapter 4K@60Hz" and get lots of results, but these cable+adapter have very cheap in-built video processors. Don't expect any performance like what you get from a real video card.

Comment: @harrymcI found that Accell has products that supports this. And it is certified by VESA. So that should work I guess. https://www.accellww.com/collections/adapters/products/displayport-1-2-to-hdmi-2-0-adapter

Comment: Aren't you forgetting you need a video adapter somewhere in the chain?

Comment: @harrymc Type-C becomes the video adapter, yeah? correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: No,  it's just a port, no inbuilt adapter. Don't confuse yourself.

Comment: A port passes information, it does not create it.

Comment: @harrymc so If I buy an adapter like this  [adapter](https://plugable.com/products/usbc-hdmi/) it should work yeah? since the adapter does the switching or conversion it requires?

Comment: If anyone's confused about this whole thing, this should clear up some doubts you have. https://superuser.com/q/1192638/540572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a Type C to HDMI 2.0 Adapter like the one you found.

This will work, within limits. Such a cable incorporates a simple video adapter,
not up to the same standards as a full-fledged video card.

Depending on your needs, and especially if it is for gaming, search for one on
a merchant website offering client evaluations, for example on Amazon,
looking for testimonies from users that had the same needs.

Comment: But that‘s not necessarily correct. If the adapter is just an active DP-HDMI converter, the laptop’s GPU will still do all the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I take advantage of my USB Type-C port with DP alt mode to achieve 4K@60Hz?

Yes. There is a caveat though: The DisplayPort version (and thus maximum resolution) isn’t specified and you need to look it up in your laptop’s specs. Still, chances are good that it supports 4K 60 Hz.

> What cables or adapters do I need if this is possible?

Something like [this](https://www.startech.com/AV/usb-c-video-adapters/usb-c-hdmi-adapter~CDP2HD4K60W).

> Can there be issues when connecting multiple converters? (Like USB Type-C -> DP -> HDMI).

Yes, mainly with power. USB-C can only provide power to the first adapter. The next adapter could then not receive enough power and would need an additional power connection.

> Also, does my USB Type-C support HDMI in alt mode as well?

While there is apparently indeed a specification for HDMI Alt Mode, I haven’t seen any device supporting it. It is also restricted to HDMI 1.4b.

Comment: It's really confusing when it comes down to these type of port tech

Comment: The problem really is that most OEMs suck at writing specs. If they would simply lay out all the facts (which modes a specific USB-C port on a device supports for example), life would be so much easier. Instead the just write “Thunderbolt 3.0”.

Comment: Yeah exactly. It's super annoying when you purchase the item and find out that it's not gonna support your requirements. It's indirect false advertising mostly I would say. They sneak in really important information somewhere they know the consumer will most likely ignore and just purchase the item because the product has a general name on it.

Comment: _Regarding converters_: Can confirm that on similar laptop model (HP PROBOOK 450 G6 w/Intel UHD 620 graphics), USBC->DP worked but USBC->DP->HDMI did not work.

Comment: @nobar I was able to find a USB-C -> HDMI adapter from Pluggable which worked flawlessly. USB-C -> DP -> HDMI daisy chaining as you said wouldn't work most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

HP probook G5 can run 4k 60Hz over USB-C DisplayPort Altmode, but you will lose USB3 functionality on that port, it will be USB2. There is a property in bios for this.

Comment: Yeah, I mostly use that port to charge or connect my TV as an external display. I was able to find a proper converter thanks guys at Pluggable.

Comment: Would you kindly detail the property in BIOS?